# What is a state in <Link> component of React Router?

Tags: react-router

Here is a screenshot from their docs about `<Link>` [component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt5zs.png)

[image]

1. What `state` do they mean? A `Redux` state?
2. How does it look like to pass a state? Like this?

   ```
       pathname: '/foo',
       query: {
           x: this.props.x,
       },
       state: store.getState()
   ```

Comment: "A Redux state?" - The `react-router` itself do not know about `redux`. The `react-router-redux` know about `redux`.

Comment: Did you find any of the answers below helpful?

Comment: This is a pretty clear explanation: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-link/

Answer (score 22):

It's a piece of information that you'd like to send to the next page. Nothing to do with Redux. It's a plain object. I believe Flipkart is a very nice example of how it can be used to improve user experience:

- Go to a [Flipkart search page](https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=shirt&marketplace=FLIPKART&sid=search.flipkart.com) on a mobile device (or simulate one using Chrome DevTools)
- Tap on one of the items

You'll see that the transition happens instantly and pieces of information like product images, title, rating and price are readily available on the product page. One way to implement that is passing the state they had already loaded on the search page onto the next one:

```js
<Link
  to={`/product/${id}`}
  state={{
    product,
  }}
/>
```

And then:

```js
function ProductPage(props) {
  // Always check because state is empty on first visit
  if (props.location.state.product) {
    console.log(props.location.state.product);
    // { id: '...', images: [...], price: { ... } }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a tried the same but I do not get anything in the props in my functional component?
<Link
                          to={{
                            pathname:
                            //"/calls/"+ props.current_record.campaign_ID + "/" + props.current_record.name 
                            "/calls2",
                            search: "?campaign_id=" + props.current_record.campaign_ID + "&campaign_name=" + props.current_record.name,
                            state: { fromCampaign: true }
                          }}
                        >

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to pass data from one route to another via Link.

- URL Parameter.
- As state.

URL parameter help when the route params contain strings for example we want to route to a particular profile:
`<Link to='/azheraleem'>Visit Profile</Link>`

However, the later i.e. the state helps us pass data from one route to another which is complex data structure. (objects/arrays).
As per the react router [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-string), in case of passing data from one route to another it can be done as per the below code sample:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/profile",
    search: "?name=azheraleem",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

The pathname is the link to the route while the search attribute contains the query string parameters, thus the on clicking the link the URL will form something like:
http://localhost:3000/profile?name=azheraleem.

But the state variable value can be accessed in the called route using the useLocation hook:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

const profile() => {
   let data = useLocation();
   console.log(data.state.fromDashboard);
}
```

Comment: state as attribute is not working, passing as object to "to" works

Comment: Note that this is for React v5, v6 has a different `<Link />` signature

Answer (score 5):

The the `state` property of the `to` prop is the param of `pushState` method of `History` DOM object [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

That props used in `push`/`replace` methods of router [as described here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc) for transitions to a new URL, adding a new entry in the browser history like this:

```js
router.push('/users/12')

// or with a location descriptor object
router.push({
  pathname: '/users/12',
  query: { modal: true },
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
})
```

It also mentioned [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#programmatic-navigation):

```js
router.push(path)
router.push({ pathname, query, state }) // new "location descriptor"

router.replace(path)
router.replace({ pathname, query, state }) // new "location descriptor"
```

Comment: OP isn't referring to the props, but to the properties of the `to` prop. See OP picture.

Answer (score 4):

`state` is a property that's part of the object you can provide to the `to` prop of the `<Link>` component.

It is particularly useful if you want to send data from the current view to one the `<Link>` directs you to, without using common techniques such as setting URL parameters or using libraries, such as `Redux`.

There isn't much official information about the `state` key, but here's what I found in the source code of that component:

> Links may pass along location state and/or query string parameters
>    in the state/query props, respectively.

So basically, it's like sending props to a component from a parent. Here, you are sending "state" from the current view to the target view. That's about it, really.

Comment: This cited message is not removed from source and `state` is not removed from form `propTypes` delaration but seems `state` not used or its using is not clear.

Comment: It used to be a prob, but now its a key of the object u provide to the "to" prop. Bur you're right.

Answer (score 2):

In simple term state in `<Link/>` component is use to pass information from one view to other view through router in form of object.On other page it can be access using `prop.location.state`.

(*Note: on browser refresh state no longer contain information*)

To pass state in Link:

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/second_page", state: {id: 123}}} />
```

To access id in second page view:

```
let id = props.location.state.id;
```

For more Link properties : [React Router Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)