# Link REACT state data in another page shows error undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to React and I am facing difficulty in accessing data passed from Link to another page.

I am in Homepage , I have a link where I am redirecting to another page or component(testpage) with state name and age. But I am not able to get the data in testpage. Below is the code I have tried.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/testpage",
    state: {
      Testname: {
        name: "im test",
        age: 20
      }
    }
  }}
>
  Hi test
</Link>
```

I want to access the state in the testpage component. So in the test page my code is given like this

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

class Testpage extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { Testname } = this.props.location.state.Testname;
    console.log(Testname);
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error

> Cannot read property 'Testname' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring from `Testname`. You should destructure from `state`

It should be:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

class Testpage extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { Testname } = this.props.location.state;
    console.log(Testname);
  }
}
```

Comment: still i am getting same error 'Testname' of undefined

Comment: @Rspp are you using `react-router`? if so, which version? although it should totally work. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57032818/6141587 & https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-link/

Comment: Yes routing is done. Im getting the page as well when i give render                 render() {
           
       return (
                <p>Hi Test page</p>
          
       );

Comment: @Rspp can you paste your route config? the above should work perfectly fine i think

Comment: <Route path="/testpage" component={ Testpage } />

Comment: @Rspp complete route config? also check out https://codedaily.io/tutorials/47/Create-a-Modal-Route-with-Link-and-Nav-State-in-React-Router if it helps. there's a codesandbox below it. it should give you an idea :)