# How can you initialize a child components state from inside a parent component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that when clicked on redirects to another component but I need to initialize the child components state from inside the parent component when the button is clicked on?

This is the button in the parent component

```
<button variant="warning" onClick={event =>  window.location.href='/member'} pro={p.publisher}>
```

and this is the child component

```
const Member = (props) => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const {pro, notes} = props;

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      h = await this.props.pro + 'hello';
      console.log(h);
      setUser(h);
    }

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
     {this.user}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Member;
```

When I click on the button it redirects to the child component but the string does not show

Comment: That isn't a child component, though. You're redirecting to an unrelated component. And you're not passing `pro` as a prop to `Member`. It's just a part of the button. There are ways to accomplish what you're after (like using LocalStorage or URL arguments), but it seems like you'd be better served by using a routing library like [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) to handle this kind of thing.

Comment: im actually already using react router on this app. How can you pass state in to the route in the routes in routes.js? Say if I did         <Route path="/member" exact component={Member} user={this.state.getThisUser} />  How could I set getThisUser in the original component above?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using `react-router-dom`, then I recommend using `Link` component.

Check the docs here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

and related SO question here: [What is a state in <Link> component of React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736048/what-is-a-state-in-link-component-of-react-router)

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: "/member",
    state: {
      pro: p.publisher
    }
  }}
/>
```

and in `Member`

```
// ..
const Member = (props) => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState("")
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (props.location.state && props.location.state.pro) {
      setProfile(props.location.state.pro)
    }
  }, [props.location.state])
}
```