# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had passed the parameter to other component through **Link**

```
{props.posts.map((post)=>{
          return (<>
          
           <tr  >
           <td>{post.title}</td>
           <td class="pull-right"   id="underline"><Link to={{pathname:"/details",state:{title:post.title}}} >Details</Link> </td>
          
       </tr>
       </>)
      })}
```

But when I tried to extract value of title in my Details component it showed error.
My Details.js is as

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Details(props) {
    return (
        <div>

            <section class="section">
                <br />
                <section class="details">
                    <h4>Title:{props.location.state.title} </h4>
                    <br />
                    <h4>Categories: </h4><br />
                    <h4>Content: </h4>
                </section>
                <br />
            </section>

        </div>

    )
}
```

I got the error as

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a state in <Link> component of React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736048/what-is-a-state-in-link-component-of-react-router)

Comment: No, I have tried all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the data from props, whereas you've passed data from the `Link` component, and not directly to the to-be-rendered component, to resolve this issue, you could make use of the `useRouter` hook.
Firstly create an instance of this hook. Use the created instance to drill through the state object.

If you're using `react-router-dom` v6 and above, there are few syntactical updates made. `path` and `state` needs to be passed as separate props and the state properties need to be wrapped within `{}`.

```
{props.posts.map((post)=>{
          return (<>
          
           <tr  >
           <td>{post.title}</td>
           <td class="pull-right" id="underline"><Link to={"/details"} state={{title:post.title}}>Details</Link> </td>
          
       </tr>
       </>)
      })}
```

**MyDetails.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Details(props) {
    const location = useLocation() //Instance of useLocation hook.
    return (
        <div>

            <section class="section">
                <br />
                <section class="details">
                    <h4>Title:{location.state.title} </h4> 
                    <br />
                    <h4>Categories: </h4><br />
                    <h4>Content: </h4>
                </section>
                <br />
            </section>

        </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: Now this error is occuring  **TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')**

Comment: Could you `console.log`, `location.state` and see what's printing?

Comment: it is printing 'null'

Comment: Which version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: react-router-dom@6.1.1

Comment: There are a few syntactical updates in v6+. I've updated the code. Kindly check.

Comment: yes, now it is running fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the answer helped you fix the issue, kindly consider marking it as accepted. Thanks.