# How to deliver data on the link tag of react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I put the state value in the link prop of the react router dom, I want to use the data I put in the state when the link was executed in the moved component, but I don't know how.

When console.log(location;), I want to see the wordlist in the state value.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/test/${wordlist[0]?.contents}`,
    state: {
      wordlist: wordlist,
    },
  }}
>
  <ColorButton>test</ColorButton>
</Link>
```

```
export default function Test(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);
return()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736048/what-is-a-state-in-link-component-of-react-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react-router v6, state is passed as a prop in Link component:

```
<Link
  to={`/test/${wordlist[0]?.contents}`}
  state={{ wordlist }}
>
  <ColorButton>test</ColorButton>
</Link>
```